# Managing Nested Horizontal Lists in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I am at a beginner level in flutter and currently ran into a blocking point , I have 2 singeltons loading 2x jsons then displaying them into my app, the blocking point is that I am currently trying to figure out if I can display the data using Nested ListViews(1 Vertical with Horizontal children).

The problem is I have 50 categories of Item Lists, I use a ListView.builder to build a list of Horizontal Lists,issue is when nesting ListView.builders the Parent ListView.builder builds all the Child lists with 4 elements each and thus there is a delay when loading the screen and when switching pages.

I cannot find a way to manage this in an elegant manner, I would like to find a way to show a loading progress indicator or similar instead of having that delay just show an empty screen, so I would appreciate any suggestions.

My current Build is something like this:

```
 Main Screen: Column -> Widgets[
    ... Bunch of Widgets(),
    CategoryList(),
]
 
 where 
 CategoryList()  is a vertical List built using: 
 ListView.builder of CategoryListItems()
 
 where 
 CategoryListItems() is a horizontal List built using : 
 ListView.builder of CategoryItem() (this is basically a card with text and   an     Image) ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to show progress indicator as I am assuming that the processing is being done asynchronously. Return circular progress indicator when the task is not complete.

Comment: No , the process is not done Async , the data loading is Async but i decided to use Provider/Consumer instead , so the data is loaded only once when the app is started , and the delay does not come from the loading, the delay is basically from the ListView.builder building the nested ListsView.builder for each category instead of the just the visible ones, this would happen also inside a  FutureBuilder unless someone could help me with a way of converting the Listview.builder to a future and use this as the future source in a FutureBuilder.

Comment: So to simplify my logic is : JSONs load async in their Singletons, each has a ChangeNotifier attached , inside the mainscreen widget a Consumer2<A,B> listens to these 2 finishing and while they are loading display a LoadingCircle, when they finish they display the widget tree , and here the delay appears due to the high complexity of the tree(~50x ListViews nested inside another ListView).